# How to remove relation between two entities

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have two tables in database: Person and Group.

Person has a foreign key to Group. In Person java class I have an int field for Group id.
If I want to cut the relation between two entities, I should set null to groupId. But Java 
has no nullable int type. How can I acheive this?

Comment: Are you working with a particular database library/ORM library, or just Android SDK?

Comment: "Java has no nullable int type". Thats simply not true. Use `Integer`instead!

Comment: Post your comment as an answer so I can check it as a correct answer!